# Ignore SSL errors in R httr connection

Tags: r, curl, https, httr

Updated:

I am trying to access a corporate internal web API using:

```
require(httr)
url = 'https://my_server/api/search/query?q=stuff'
httr::set_config( config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L) )
data <- httr::GET( url, use_proxy(url = "ipaddress:port"), verbose() )
```

I get:

```
-> CONNECT my_server:port HTTP/1.1
-> Host: my_server:port
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.47.1 r-curl/0.9.7 httr/1.1.0
-> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
<- 
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  SSL connect error
```

I used `ssl_verifypeer` as there are issues with the CA cert of the server. is that what is causing the issue with the `SSL connect error` ?

How do I bypass this and get the data?
is there a way to flick the `--insecure` option that exists if you run in the linux command line? Note I am running R on windows though.

Comment: `readLines` uses a `file` connection when given a character string, not a `url` one. Do it explicitly, or better, try [`httr`](https://github.com/hadley/httr/). Also, you have some questionable syntax.

Answer (score 20):

Simply run this line:

```
httr::set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is coming here looking for a solution for `{httr2}`, you can do it like this:

```
library(httr2)
req <- request("https://example.com") %>%
  req_options(ssl_verifypeer = 0)
```