# httr equivalent to verify in requests

Tags: python, r, python-requests, httr

In `python` I use `requests` to call an API (cannot share the API itself unfortunately so this is hard to reproduce) in the following way:

```
import requests
url = url
headers = {'API-key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
       'Content-type': 'application/json',
       'Accept': 'application/json'
       }

r = requests.get(url, headers = headers, verify=False)
print(r.text)
```

Here, I think the `verify=False` forces request to ignore the SSL certificate (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445981/how-do-i-disable-the-security-certificate-check-in-python-requests)). This works fine, however I am not able to reproduce it with `httr` the following way:

```
 library(httr)

url <- url
headers <- c('API-key' = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
             'Content-type' = 'application/json',
              'Accept' = 'application/json'
          ))

GET(url = url, add_headers(headers = headers)
```

Now, I believe that `verify=False` in the `requests` code is the key here, [someone suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36997896/ignore-ssl-errors-in-r-httr-connection) that the way to ignore SSL certificates with httr is using `set_config()` before a request:

```
httr::set_config(httr::config(ssl_verifypeer=0L, ssl_verifyhost=0L))

GET(url = url, add_headers(headers = headers))
```

But it is not working.

```
$message
[1] "Unauthorized"

$http_status_code
[1] 401
```

Is `httr::set_config(httr::config(ssl_verifypeer=0L, ssl_verifyhost=0L))` the equivalent to `verify=False` in a `requests` call?

Comment: What exactly are the errors you are getting? What type of "unauthorized" are you getting? Is it an actual response from the server or is it an SSL certificate issue? If you are asking for R help, you should describe exactly what `verify=False` does in the python request so we can tell you how to do the same with `httr`.

Comment: Sure, I have added the error message and tried to explain what `verify=False` does in `requests`. In the documentation it says: Requests can also ignore verifying the SSL certificate if you set verify to False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you showed is really a response from the server. Is has nothing to do with the SSL certificate so you don’t need to disable that checking at all.

The problem is that the name of the parameter in `add_headers` is `.headers` not `headers`. You just need to do

```
GET(url = url, add_headers(.headers = headers)
```